# preg_replace() Remove repeating characters and replace them with the corresponding characters?

Tags: php, preg-replace, repeat

```
$s='123///456***789';
```

now I try to replace repeating `///` and `***`

```
$s=preg_replace('!\/+!',"/",$s);
$s=preg_replace('!\*+!',"*",$s);
```

The result is `123/456*789` Ok

I'm trying to remove repeatings with the one pattern but I can't get how to set corresponding character for each repeating character

```
$s=preg_replace('![\/\*]+!',"/",$s);
```

The result is `123/456/789` but I need it to be like the above result - `123/456*789`

Comment: So you want to do this in 1 statement?

Comment: @E L please check my answer again. It should work now.

Comment: @E L Are there always 3 / or can there be 2 or 4 for example?

Comment: @tastro Yes. I'm curious if it's possible in one statement

Comment: @tastro I can be more then 3 and it could be any characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using back references (https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php):

```
$s='123///456***789';
$s = preg_replace ('~([\/\*])\1+~', '\1', $s);
printf ("%s\n", $s);
```

Comment: seems like it works. I'm also curious wat the `\1` means

Comment: @EL: `\1` is a reference to the "result" of the first subpattern.

Comment: There is no need to escape `/` or `*` in this case.

Comment: It's the same answer i provided before i updated it... And mine was down voted... His was chosen as the answer... o_O

Comment: @Gumbo: You're right, but I wanted to change as less as possible of the original expression. You can also say, I didn't see it when I was copying, pasting and playing :-)

Comment: @tastro: The trick is the **double** back reference, one in the regular expression and the other in the replacement.

Comment: @rkhb it's the one in the first parameter right? I tried this with $1 but it didn't work. Good to know. Thanks +1 rkhb.

Comment: But for a string like this: `123//*/456***789` it doesn't work. But again... I don't know what exactly the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `preg_replace_callback` to achieve that:

```
$s=preg_replace_callback('!(\*+|\/+)!' ,
  function($match){
    //whatever we match MULTIPLE times - replace it with one time "that".
    return substr($match[1],0,1); //first matchgroup
  }
,$s);
```

*Side note*: The Pattern `![\/\*]+!` will also match `/*/*/*` - which is not what you (maybe) want to achieve. You should use `(\*+|\/+)` instead.

*Side note 2*: Inside MatchGroups you do not need to escape. `[/*]+` would be equal to the regex you provided.

---

If you design the pattern a little more *tricky*, you can ommit the callback, and work with a backreference:

```
$s=preg_replace('!(?:(\*)\*+|(\/)\/+)!' , "$1$2", $s);
```

Explanation:

this matches *one* time either `*` or `/`, followed by 1 or more of them. Your first matchgroup (respectively second) will now contain only ONE of the sign in question. Therefore, the whole match of `***` will be replaced with your first (respectively second) match group - which is a single `*` (respectively `/`) now.

using `$1$2` as replacement *is safe*, because due to the OR (`|`) One of those matchgroups is ALWAYS empty.

But i'd prefer solution one, as it is way clearer.

Comment: Didn't try the first one. But the second one doesn't work for me. :/

Comment: @tastro: You read the comment to remove the whitspaces from the pattern?

Comment: Sorry my bad. It's working. But not for something like this: `123///*/456***789` anyways... Don't know if this is a possibility.

Comment: @tastro: For your example both are returning `123/*/456*789` - which is what is expected if i get the OP right.

Comment: I get: `$s=preg_replace("@([\/\*])[\/\*]+@i", '$1' ,$s); // input: 123/*/456*789 output: 123/456*789` with my example. But it doesn't matter anyways. Too many chat comments already. ;)